# ArcGIS REST API not enough storage available to complete the operation

Tags: api, web-service, rest

I am building a web app for submitting jobs to the [Vehicle Routing Problem Solver](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/network/api-reference/vehicle-routing-problem-service.htm). I have been testing this app for a while now and I could submit jobs flawlessly before, but as of today I am getting:

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
```

in the JSON response.

I am submitting the exact same job parameters every time and have done so many dozens of times before. All of the 'save' parameters for the job are set to default (false) and I have more than enough credits in my organization.

What is the cause of this issue?

EDIT: I have submitted the example job in the docs using postman and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you making use of a Public account? Those accounts are limited to 2gb of storage. I believe named users have unlimited space.  Or are you using a trail developer account?

Comment: @KHibma I am using an ArcGIS organization account and I have publisher privileges.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Online or your own ArcGIS server install? If your own, its possible that the jobs folder is full and causing issues. I.e. install path - >arcgisserver\directories

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Online. The issue was actually Esri's logistics server, it was down at the time of posting. The issue has since been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this:

This error was returned due to ArcGIS Online logistics server being down. There was no [abnormal status](https://status.arcgis.com/) at the time of posting. If you encounter this error I would recommend reporting to Esri if they are not already aware of the issue.